# passing modal-content with php or javascript

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap

What I am dying to do is, open a new tab (my site) and launch a modal when the tab is loaded. My modal is getting the modal content from a different php class here is the code for that class:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
```

```
<div class="modal-body copycode">
    <h4>Here's your Coupon Code</h4>
    <p>Paste this code at checkout when you are done shopping.</p>
    <span class="get-code" id="voucher_code_<?=$coupon->deal_id?>_get">
        <?=$coupon->voucher_code;?></span>
    <p><a class="copy-code" target="_blank" id="<?=$coupon->deal_id?>" 
          href="<?=site_url();?>deal/deal_exitclick_id/<?=$store->store_id;?>
          /<?=$coupon->deal_id;?>">Copy Code</a>
        </p>
        <a target="_blank" href="<?=site_url();?>deal/deal_exitclick_id
          /<?=$store->store_id;?>/<?=$coupon->deal_id;?>">Click here to go to
          <?=$store->name;?> >>></a>
 </div>
```

and this is how i am calling the webpage:

```
<a href="<?=site_url();?>front/popup_login_simple/<?php echo $row->store_id;?>" 
   class="get-code" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#retailorPopup">
```

which fills the modal-content here

```
  <div id="copy_code<?=$i;?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

        </div>
```

the last two code snippets are in the same class fyi
  anyone know how i would go about solving this issue?

Comment: Where is the problem? What is it you need help with?

Comment: i need to add content remotely( from an external link) in a new tab.

Comment: That does not explain the problem in any way. What have you tried, where did it go wrong, what data do you want to add... in general we just need _a lot_ more information